# How can use the ( ' ) symbol in DELPHI Edit components?

Tags: delphi

How can allow the usage of the symbol (') in DELPHI TEdit and other components ?

Comment: In what way have you found that it's *not* allowed in those components? Put a TEdit on your form. Run the program. Type as many apostrophes as you want into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok done some test and all you guys where correct. 
The symbol is allowed.

The problem is with devExpress tools. Some of them are not prepared to allow it.

Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 5):

If you want the end-user to be able to type it, then you have to do nothing (he/she can already). If you want to use the character in strings in Delphi code, write `''` instead, as in

```
const
  s = 'This isn''t good.';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a double ', e.g. 'What''s up'